# List all tables,numrows,numcol and primary key for table if any in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I want to QUERY to generate a table like below:

```
Tablename||noofrows||noofcolumns||PRIMARKEYCOL(IF ANY for the table)
xyz.       590.         11.           xyz_id
bcd.       934          15            null
...
...
```

So far I was able to do this until now in 2 query:

Query 1:

```
select a.table_name,count_rows(a.table_name) total_rows,count(b.column_name) total_cols from user_tables a,
     ,user_tab_columns b
where a.table_name =b.table_name 
and a.table_name not like('amp%')
group by a.table_name;
```

note:Count_rows() is function to calculate rows as stats are not up to date

query 2:

```
select b.table_name b.column_name PRIMKEY_COL FROM user_constraints a,user_cons_columns b
where 
a.constraint_type = 'P'
and a.constraint_name=b.constraint_name 
and a.table_name=b.table_name
and b.table_name not like ('amp%');
```

**Problem**

I need to merge this table to one query (as shown in example above) so that I can represent the data in one table. My issue in clubbing the table is, with joins and how to make sure  table without any primary keys are represent because if I just directly give constraint type ='p' in the where clause of the join I see that it only shows table with  Primarykeys I am not able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary key can have more than just a single column, so - if you'd want to return them all, you'd either have to "aggregate" them, somehow (`listagg` looks like a natural choice, but - in 12c - you can't fetch `distinct` list of columns which you might need because of joining those tables duplicates *appear*).

As you already use a function to return number of rows (you'd probably rather regularly collect statistics, though, but yes - if tables are frequently modified (inserts and deletes), counting on-the-fly is the way to go.

So, alternative approach with 2 functions and 1 simple query. Yes, I know - context switching and stuff, but - see if it does any good.

This is what you already have (see if your and my code look similar):

```
SQL> create or replace function count_rows (par_table_name in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    -- return number of rows in PAR_TABLE_NAME
  5    retval number;
  6  begin
  7    execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' ||
  8      dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table_name) into retval;
  9    return retval;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

This is *new* (to simplify fetching distinct list of primary key columns):

```
SQL> create or replace function pk_cols (par_table_name in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    -- return list of primary key columns for PAR_TABLE_NAME, sorted by column's
  5    -- position within the primary key constraint
  6    retval varchar2(100);
  7  begin
  8    select listagg(b.column_name, ', ') within group (order by b.position)
  9      into retval
 10      from user_constraints a join user_cons_columns b on b.constraint_name = a.constraint_name
 11      where upper(a.table_name) = dbms_assert.sql_object_name(upper(par_table_name))
 12        and a.constraint_type = 'P';
 13    return retval;
 14  end;
 15  /

Function created.
```

Finally, that *simple query* I mentioned:

```
SQL> select a.table_name,
  2         count_rows(a.table_name) total_rows,
  3         max(a.column_id) total_cols,
  4         pk_cols(a.table_name) primkey_cols
  5  from user_tab_columns a
  6  group by a.table_name;

TABLE_NAME      TOTAL_ROWS TOTAL_COLS PRIMKEY_COLS
--------------- ---------- ---------- -------------------------
DEPT                     4          3 DEPTNO
SO_TEST                  0          1
TEST                     7          3 ORD, TERMREGIONAL
EMP                     14          8 EMPNO
TRAINING                 0          5 TRAINING_PLACE_ID
TEMP_SE                 10          3
<snip>
```

Comment: Hey This was exactly what I needed works  great for my usecase.   Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

Just join the two queries:

```
select tab_cols.*, tab_keys.* from 
(select a.table_name,count_rows(a.table_name) total_rows,count(b.column_name) total_cols from user_tables a,
     ,user_tab_columns b
where a.table_name =b.table_name 
and a.table_name not like('amp%')
group by a.table_name) tab_cols,
(select b.table_name b.column_name PRIMKEY_COL FROM user_constraints a,user_cons_columns b
where 
a.constraint_type = 'P'
and a.constraint_name=b.constraint_name 
and a.table_name=b.table_name
and b.table_name not like ('amp%')) tab_keys
where tab_cols.table_name = tab_keys.table_name(+);
```

Comment: Hi , Tried ur code as well seems to have some syntax related issue made some changes  but still not able to execute also what I need was as Aggregation like in the above post ... But thanks for your time